# After clicking button make it disabled for a while (XCode)

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'd like to know how can I make a button disable for few seconds after clicking it. I can disable it with code

> button.enabled = button.enabled = NO;

But I'm not sure how it can be done for just few seconds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this code:

```
double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    button.enabled = NO;
});
```

EDIT: If you want to disable your button first and execute some code later on, do this:

```
button.enabled = NO;
double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    //this will be executed after 2 seconds
});
```

Comment: It does do what you initially asked for. I have tested it and it works just fine. However, now I think you want to disable the button and execute some other code after some time interval. I will edit my answer to provide a code for that.

Comment: If you want to re-enable tour button after the interval, just enable it like this: `button.enabled = YES;` after you execute your code.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(setButtonEnabled) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

-(void)setButtonEnabled{
    [myButton setEnabled:YES]
}
```

after you set the button invisible

Comment: I just want to make it disabled not invisible. I need some code for time interval to write after that first code which makes it disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Adam.

For Swift 3.0 :

```
button.isEnabled = false
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(2000)) {
        btnCheckout.isEnabled = true
}
```